# REGEXP_SUBSTR equivalent in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, regex

I migrate from Oracle DB to Postgres/MS-SQL and I want to use REGEXP_SUBSTR equivalent with these databases. I need to rewrite this statement to these databases:

```
SELECT b.id,
       b.name,
       b.description,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(b.description, '(st|ek)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) substring
FROM books b;
```

I was able to write this statement for PostgreSQL as:

```
SELECT b.id,
       b.name,
       b.description,
       (SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM REGEXP_MATCHES(b.description, '(st|ek) ', 'g') AS f(a) LIMIT 1) substring
FROM books b;
```

However I have no idea how to rewrite to MS-SQL db. I tried to used statement below however bad result is returned for substring column. Is any solution for this issue please?

```
 SELECT b.id,
           b.name,
           b.description,
           (SELECT SUBSTRING(b.description, PATINDEX('(st|ek)', CAST(b.description AS varchar)), LEN(b.description))) substring
 FROM books b;
```

Comment: The Postgres solution is probably better done using `substring(b.description from '(st|ek)')` - but it's unclear to me if you are looking for a Postgre**s** solution or a SQL Server solution or both. It would also help, if you added sample data and the expected output.

Comment: I want to support both databases. Oracle request: SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('one two three four five', '(\S+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) substring
FROM DUAL; Expected result: one

Comment: There is no way you'll get a single statement running on both products - it might better to ask two separate questions. For Postgres use: `substring('one two three four five' from '(\S+)')`

Comment: The statement will be used according to used DB...

Comment: You should still ask two questions. If you get one answer for Postgres and one answer for SQL Server which one should be accepted? Neither can, because they don't answer the whole question.

Comment: The app should support both databases. During start the proper DB setting are loaded (for one db only) and in the code is called proper statement for given db...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for Postgres is to use `substring()`

```
substring('one two three four five' from '(\S+)')
```

yields `one`. The biggest difference to Oracle's `regexp_substring()` is that you can't locate the "nth" occurance directly. To get the second word, you could use:

```
substring('one two three four five' from '\S+\s*(\S+)')
```

If you are trying to access words (separated by whitespace), then splitting the string into an array is another alternative:

```
(regexp_split_to_array('one two three four five', '\s+'))[1]
```

The above returns the first word, `[2]`  would return the second. The regex defines the *separator* (delimiter) between each element.

---

Note that Postgres 15 will have a `regexp_substr()` that is pretty much identical to Oracle's implementation.